# Htaccess remove filename from url

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to remove the single.php ? how would i go about this ?, i have tried the following:

so EG. www.mysite.com/single.php/contact/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is it needed just for `single.php`?

Comment: yes :) want to replace the single.php file so that the new url reads www.sitename.com/page1 instead of www.sitename.com/single.php/page1

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ single.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: There rules are tested and working on my Apache. Check your Apache error.log for the cause of 500